# Website doesn't want to load image in div style

Tags: html, css

I have div with background-image property but it doesn't want to load.

My code:

```
<div class="product_div" style="background-image: url("img/products/test.jpg")"></div>
```

My css:

```
.mainpage .new_products .product {
    border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.mainpage .new_products .product .product_div {
    max-height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: And the image exists in that location? Do other styles override it?

Comment: I tryed it with img src and it works

Comment: try this `style="background-image: url('img/products/test.jpg')"`

Comment: Can you show what other CSS you have on that element. Something must be messing with it.

Comment: Does the div have content?

Comment: I edited my question with CSS

Comment: @astonearachnid no he didn't.

Comment: @Martys you haven't set a `height` or `width`, I'm guessing the image is working, you just can't see it because of this.

Comment: @astonearachnid I have there class="...."

Comment: Try adding @ before the quotes. That would be a direct link.

Answer (score 3):

You're using a double-quoted URL inside a double-quoted HTML attribute. That's not going to have good results. Use single quotes in the CSS.

If that doesn't fix it, remember that your image path is relative to the HTML document. It might be better to do a root-relative URL — basically, if the image is at

```
https://example.com/theme/img/products/test.jpg
```

, then try putting

```
url('/theme/img/products/test.jpg')
```

in your style attribute.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you haven't set a `width` or a `height` on the image, just a `max-width` and `max-height`. This means the `div` doesn't have any dimensions and thus won't show the image. I'm guessing that if you give it these dimensions that it will work:

```css
.product_div {
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product_div" style="background-image: url('https://placeimg.com/640/480/any')"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bzah8us7/

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, the url is between ' '-s, not ""-s. Maybe the / is missing before img.

```
<div class="product_div" style="background-image: url('/img/products/test.jpg')"></div>
```

Comment: I tryed that but same

Comment: Then the image path is not correct. Could you paste a screen about your current working directory?
Meanwhile you could try image path, like products/test.jpg or /img/products/test.jpg

Maybe the / is  missing before img.